# Vim enters into visual mode on selecting text after El Capitan update

Tags: vim, copying, osx-elcapitan

Issue is what the title says. Earlier I used to copy text from text files open in `vim` simply by selecting text and doing `Ctrl + C`. But now it puts me into visual mode, thus not allowing to copy the text. Its really annoying. Anybody knows any fix for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You probably have the `mouse` mode active. You can turn it off with:

```
:set mouse=
```

And turn it back on with

```
:set mouse=a
```

**iTerm users**

If you are using iTerm, you can leave mouse mode on all the time if you want, and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> when you want to select without using visual mode. I am not aware of a way to do that in OS X Terminal.

**Update** (from Younes in comments): For Terminal.app on El Capitan, press the Fn key to bypass the mouse mode. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/125102/mac-os-x-terminal-mouse-support/985865#985865) for more.

Comment: For Terminal.app on El Capitan, press the Fn key to bypass the mouse mode. See this http://superuser.com/questions/125102/mac-os-x-terminal-mouse-support/985865#985865