# Odd cursor when using vim in bash shell after update to El Capitan 10.11.3

Tags: bash, vim, osx-elcapitan

I've updated my OS to El Capitan, on a MacBookPro. When I use vim in a bash shell, the cursor is odd. It appears as a cross, no longer as a vertical line, and, although I can still highlight stuff, I cannot copy or cut anything.

Comment: In your `.vimrc` comment out the mouse, e.g.: `"   set mouse=a`. or press `CMD-R`.

Comment: excellent, did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In *El Capitan*, Apple modified Terminal.app to recognize some of the xterm mouse protocol.  Unlike xterm, you cannot use <kbd>shift</kbd> while selecting/pasting to temporarily bypass the feature (reportedly you can use <kbd>FN</kbd>), or you can simply turn it off in the applications that enable it, such as vim.

Further reading:

- [Vim enters into visual mode on selecting text after El Capitan update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077429/vim-enters-into-visual-mode-on-selecting-text-after-el-capitan-update)
- [Mac OS X Terminal: mouse support?](https://superuser.com/questions/125102/mac-os-x-terminal-mouse-support/985865#985865)
- [*mouse-using*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html#mouse-using) (Vim documentation)